# android app can't be uninstalled. it keeps crashing the app manager

Tags: java, android

I developed a quiz app for a project using Android Studio. The app worked fine and did what i expected it to do.

Recently i tried to update the data base so i needed to uninstall the app, but it keep crashing the default app manager on my Samsung Galaxy S6 phone.

Any ideas about what might be the reason for the crashing and not letting me to uninstall it??

Comment: Are there any logs/error messages etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use adb to install/uninstall apps

```
adb uninstall <Your package name here>
```

Note:

- You have to run the above in command prompt
- You need adb installed on your machine
  and set %PATH% variable before trying

If app manager is crashing - it is perhaps not connected with your app - something else must be an issue:

1. Try to restart your phone (if still not try next option)
2. Try to reset your phone (Long press volume down and power button)